# Angular7 Detect change of input value in reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am working for the first time with reactive forms in Angular(v7)

I want to make my submit button enabled if any of the fields has changed. So I am working with the `dirty` value of the form.
For a simple scenarios its working. I change a input type text and the button became enable.

But now I got a problem with an element (`<span id="locationUpdated">`) that the value inside of it is being changed by the result of some other javascript functions.

So I decided to listening the change of an `hidden` input that get the value the same way as the `span` element

```
    <form [formGroup]="model.form" >
        ....
        <input id="nameInput" type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="model.user.name"
            formControlName="name" />           
        ...
        <span [textContent]="model.user.location.label" id="locationUpdated"></span>    

        <input type="hidden" [value]="model.user.location.label" formControlName="location" />
        ....        
        <button [ngClass]="{'disabled': !model.form.dirty}></button>

    </form>
```

--- Component ---

```
private buildFormUpdated() {
    this.model.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: [this.model.user.name,  [Validators.required]],
        location: [this.model.user.location.label]
    });
}
```

I replace the `hidden` to `text` so I can see the value change and it is working fine.

However the property `dirty` continues `false`. If I change manually I get the `dirty:true`

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain "But now I got a problem with an element (<span id="locationUpdated">) that the value inside of it is being changed by the result of some other javascript functions." in more detail?

Comment: I suggest you take a thorough read of the documentation, since first of all you shouldn't use ngModel with reactive forms, secondly do not use `value` with reactive forms. DOCS: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: To get input value changes in reactive forms you can just subscribe to `FormControl.valueChanges`

Comment: NEVER,NEVER,NEVER use [(ngModel)] together formControlName.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

The dirty flag is not set to true when the data is changed programatically. 
It is set to true only if the user blurs the control component, or changes the value (through the UI)

Please ref official docs - https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#why-check-dirty-and-touched

Answer (score 0):

you can explicit marks the control as dirty by doing this after your logic
this.model.form.markAsDirty();